# async javascript function issue

Tags: javascript

I am having problem with javascript function callback.

For example I have code like this:

```
var BASE = {

    // Constructor of the class
    createNew: function(name) {
        var base = {};

        base.ajax = function(callback, url) {
            // Create XMLHTTPRequest object
            var httpRequest;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Check status of our request
                // this is called on every state change
                if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
                    // call the callback function
                    callback.call(httpRequest.responseText);
                }
            };

            httpRequest.open("GET", some_url, true);
            httpRequest.send();
        };


        return base;
    }
};
```

and then create a class that inherits BASE:

```
var Test = {

    createNew: function() {

        var test = BASE.createNew();

        test.json = {};

        test.ajax( function(){
            test.json = JSON.parse( this );
        });

        return test;
    }
};
```

And then I create another class call myTest that inherits Test:

```
// create class for 300x250    
var myTest = {
    createNew: function() {
        var mytest = Test.createNew();
        return mytest;
    }
};

var mytest = myTest.createNew();

console.log(mytest.json);
```

However, when I try to console.log(mytest.json), I can't get the data. I know it's because in the Test class, json is in the ajax function, but I don't know how to solve this async problem, any idea?

Comment: Is this copy and past of your code? You write `var delwebb = BASE.createNew();` and it seems that it should be `var test = BASE.createNew();`.

Comment: In your second snippet, where is ``test`` defined in your ``Test`` object?

Comment: Additionally, in your examples you call `ajax` on `test` but do not provide a url. `ajax` in `base` expects url, but then later `some_url` is used. Once more, in `JSON.parse( this );` `this` might not be referencing the object you are expecting.

Comment: code has been updated